# Why is there a ZeroR and OneR classifier but no TwoR classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using WEKA, and I noticed that there is a ZeroR classifier and a OneR classifier. The ZeroR classifier always predicts the majority class, while the OneR classifier bases its predictions on only one attribute. Why are there no TwoR, ThreeR, FourR, etc. classifiers that base predictions on two or more attributes? Is there a fundamental reason for the omission?

Comment: The generalization of this idea is a decision tree. Limiting the number of nodes corresponds to k-rules. Decision trees are implemented in Weka; I don't know about all of the available configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the classifiers can use more than one feature. That’s a whole family of [rule-based machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_machine_learning) algorithms, [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree), and many other algorithms that combine information learned from different features.